# Event Source question

Tags: logging, event-log

Why does some characters are appended in my event source name XXXXXXXXXXXX?

The Event Viewer says this:

The description for Event ID ( 5 ) in Source ( XXXXXXXXXXXXtings\All Usõ ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: XXXXXXXXXXXXtings\All Usõ.

Answer (score 0):

The eventID that you supplied while logging the message to the Windows Event Viewer is not defined in your "message DLL".